# First React component: Getting error if I name component as App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and got weird error. If I name my component as "App" then get the following error:
expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

But if I rename it to Apps then it works fine. Below is code snippet:

```
function App(){
    return <h1> hiiii</h1>;
}
export default App;
```

---

```
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import Test from './Test';
import Apps from './Apps';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

console.log (App);
console.log(Test);
ReactDom.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Even console.log(App) also shows null object.
Can anyone tell me the reason for it?

Comment: Structuring your code in a question is important. The way you wrote here would suggest all this code is in a single file hence would be terrible. Assuming it is not, make sure your import is correct as the file, that has `App` component, is actually called `App.jsx` (or `App.tsx` if using typescript) and nothing else. ALSO as a tip: should ditch `function` and other old school stuff and switch to ES6 as its becoming (if hasint already became world-wide) standard.

Comment: The above code are from two different files. 1st one is from App.js and other one is Index.js

Comment: @KunalSharma That's why Lith asked you to separate them because it is really confusing to read.

Comment: From App.js? React components have to be `.jsx` format (or `.tsx` for typescript) not plain `.js`. Have you tried switching from `App.js` to `App.jsx`?